# gdb debugger in xcode doesn't work

Tags: xcode, gdb

I'm trying to use direct commands to gdb through xcode's console window when the program is paused.  But the (gdb) prompt just accepts the carriage returns, and does nothing.  Has anyone encountered this? I'm on the latest version of Mac OS X (10.6.2) with the XCode 3.2 beta.

Comment: Do you have any stdio input going on, e.g. scanf ?

Comment: Nope, nothing.  This is still happening on 3.2.3 final release...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the software, or an incompatibility with some setting in my system.  Formatting my laptop and reinstalling the software fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If using a beta best to contact the beta mailing lists as this is the sort of issue the developers want to know.

If using a beta the first thing I would check is does this work using the previous production version

Also note that you might be under a NDA and so can only discuss with the developers.